# How use rgrep for only org AND java files?

Tags: rgrep

Linux Mint 20

Emacs 27.2

I want to find text **end** in the org files in my folder (recursively).
So I use **rgrep**

```
M-x rgrep 

*.org
```

Here steps:

step 1:
[image]

step 2:
[image]

step 3 (result):
[image]

Nice. As result I found text **end** only in the org files.

But... now I want to found text **end** in the **org** files AND **java** files.

How I can do this?

```
M-x rgrep

*.org, *.java not help
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `*.org, *.java`, say `*.org *.java` at the second prompt (no comma).

Note: to input   in such completion prompt, type `C-q SPC` (that is, hold `Ctrl` and press `q`, then release `Ctrl` and hit `Space`).

Comment: At the second prompt when  I input *.org SPACE then show message "No match". So as result I can't input "*.org SPACE *.java"

Comment: Ah, yes. To input a "bare" space in such completion prompt, type `C-q SPC`. I agree it's a misfeature, but there are users who like that SPC is bound to some command that initiates completion. You can argue against this using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.